# How do I get Spark installed on Amazon's EMR core/worker nodes/instances while creating the cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cluster-computing, amazon-emr

I am trying to launch a EMR cluster with Spark (1.6.0) and Hadoop (Distribution: Amazon 2.7.1) applications. The release label is **emr-4.4.0**.
The cluster gets setup as needed but it doesn't run Spark master (in the master instances) as a daemon process and also I cannot find Spark being installed in the worker (core) instances (the Spark dir under ***/usr/lib/*** has just ***lib*** and ***yarn*** directories).

I'd like to run the Spark master and worker nodes as soon as the cluster has been setup. (i.e., workers connect to the master automatically and become a part of the Spark cluster).

How do I achieve this? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Spark on EMR is installed in YARN mode. This is the reason why you are not able to see standalone masters and slave daemons. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Standalone Spark master and worker daemons are spawned only in spark-standalone mode.  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Now, if you do want to run spark masters and  workers on EMR, you can do so using

```
/usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-master.sh
/usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-slave.sh
```

and configuring accordingly.